# Bit OT: Looking for a multi-track player that can chase SMPTE or MTC

Tags: playback, multichannel, chase, smpte

<sup>If this is too off-topic here I can move it, maybe to Video Production?</sup>

I'm looking for a device or Mac/PC app that can play six audio tracks (WAV preferred) in sync with incoming SMPTE or Midi timecode. In theory this should be possible with any laptop but I don't see anything out there.

Also useful would be any QT (video) player that can chase TC, I could just ignore the video tracks.

Comment: In my view, a question related to an audio player that can chase TC is perfectly on-topic here. But maybe you might have more answers if you explained what is the end goal of your setup.

Comment: @audionuma  Thanks for the comment. If the question is unclear I'll try to restate it but I'm not looking for alternatives, just this specific thing.